# How to enable global menu for PhpStorm in 13.10

Tags: unity, 13.10, menu, .desktop, globalmenu

I've installed PhpStorm in `/opt/phpstorm` and after first run there is file `~./local/share/applications/jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PhpStorm
Icon=/opt/phpstorm/bin/webide.png
Exec="/opt/phpstorm/bin/phpstorm.sh" %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-phpstorm
```

I've tried with `Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1 /opt/phpstorm/bin/phpstorm.sh` but that doesn't work.

So, my question is how to move menu bar (File, edit, etc) from PhpStorm window to the top bar as seen in other applications in order to get more working space and better system integration? I think this is also issue with other Jetbrains products like WebStorm, Idea, etc.

Comment: please accept the below answer ... it is working fine

Answer (score 7):

Simply install the "jayatana" package and restart the system.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danjaredg/jayatana
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jayatana
```

You will also need to enable the "GTK+" theme in PHPStorm (File -> Settings -> Appearance), otherwise I don't think it will work.

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/get-unity-global-menu-hud-support-for.html)

Comment: it works like charm on Ubuntu 14.04 and Phpstorm 7.x ( GTK+" theme is not required, I'm using "Darcula" without anyissue )

Comment: And logout and login back

Answer (score 2):

From `Ubuntu 15` `jayantana` is installed by default but the global menu is disabled by default. Because `jayantana` crashes some java swing packages, if it doesn't you can activate globally or per application base.

1. Globally

Create a file called `jayatana.conf` in `/usr/share/upstart/sessions/` location and fill it with following data

```
description "Java Ayatana"

start on starting dbus

script
 initctl set-env --global JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"
end script
```

2. Per application

Add this line at the bottom of your application startup script

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"
```

Comment: I've been using the globally option for some time now. Seems to be working awesome.

Comment: yes it was for me as well, after some day, i faced occasional crashes, specially idea IDE. but webstorm or phpStorm is working fine

Answer (score 1):

You might also need to modify vmoptions file for your IDE. Here you will find instructions for various Java apps, including, specifically, Intellij IDEA and Android Studio: http://www.javahelps.com/2015/06/global-menu-support-for-java.html. Notice though that for PhpStorm the vmoptions file is called "phpstorm.vmoptions". This page helped me to get it working (merely adding jayatana package was not enough on my 15.10)